# Other programs from software and updates

Tags: 20.10, delete

Peace everyone
I need help, so I have all this on the list what do I need and what should I remove
want to upgrade my system and I need to know, what of these unneeded at this point
Note: I am an Amuture really, I am just asking for advice if any of those just taking space and have put a load on the system, I don't need it.
[image]

Comment: Why would you want to remove them? What is the actual problem? Kindly [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1338255/edit) the question. Also note that Ubuntu 19.10 (which the screenshot shows) is an End of Life Release. You can upgrade to 20.04 LTS which will be supported until April 2025.

Comment: 19.10 may an actual install media. Now it is groovy, 20.10.  Removal of repositories may harm your system if you have installed packages from these 3rd-party repositories.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi So, I am already using 20.10 , I am just asking if those have any value at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

This question is vague and some kind of multi-variant.

**Details**

Better tool to determine the actual solution is Synaptic Package Manager which is installable by `sudo apt-get install synaptic`. Here you can navigate to Origin tab and then sort list by clicking on PPA/repository name and then S (status) in the listing.

For example below is the screenshot from my daily driver system:

[image: 18.04]

The above screenshot tells us that there are packages installed (they have green rectangle in the list) from flatpak PPA. So removal of the PPA will transform its packages to obsolete or locally installed. This is not recommended.

Other PPAs like LibreOffice should be removed with their packages. The special application named `ppa-purge` should be used in this case. This will lead to downgrade of the LibreOffice to the version from official repository.

It is safe to remove the PPA which does not have any packages installed.

**Analysis of your list**

- *dl.google.com/linux/chrome* is needed to have auto-upgrade of Google Chrome, thus should not removed;
- *bookworm* is [not officially packaged for 20.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=bookworm), thus PPA should not removed;
- *elementary-os* PPA is needed for styling, thus PPA should not removed;
- *fingerprint* PPA is needed for fingerprint scanner, thus PPA should not removed;

Comment: Thank you, another Q: why there is a lot of not installed PPA  , are those something I left over time? ( when hitting state at Synaptic)

Comment: Packages maybe leftovers, maybe really not installed. Some PPAs may be disabled (commented by `#` in */etc/apt/sources.list* or */etc/apt/sources.list.d/\*.list*), you can activate them later. Usually PPAs are disabled on Ubuntu version upgrade (for example from 19.10 → 20.04 an then on 20.04 → 20.10)